# Need the username in a field after successfully login in php

Tags: php

i am facing issue to take the username after successfully login.

Below is the code for login:

```
<?php
//validation error
if(isset($_REQUEST['validationError']))
{
    if($_REQUEST['validationError']==1)
    {
        $username='Username required';
    }
    if($_REQUEST['validationError']==2)
    {
        $password='Password required';
    }
    if($_REQUEST['validationError']==3)
    {
        $not_match='User not exist. Please give correct information';
    }
}
?>
    <p><span style="color:red;display:<?php echo isset($not_match)?'block':'none' ?>"><?php echo isset($not_match)?$not_match:''; ?><span></p>

    <p><input size="40px" type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['username'])?$_POST['username']:''; ?>" value="" placeholder="Username"></p>

    <p><span style="color:red;display:<?php echo isset($username)?'block':'none' ?>"><?php echo isset($username)?$username:''; ?><span></p>

    <p><input size="40px" type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>
    <p><span style="color:red;display:<?php echo isset($password)?'block':'none' ?>"><?php echo isset($password)?$password:''; ?><span></p>

    <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"></p>
 </form>
```

Below is the code for login check:

```
if($username !='' && $password !='')
{
    include('database_connection.php');
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from user WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
    {
        $validationError=3;  
    }
}


if(isset($validationError) && $validationError==0)
{
    //session set
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['isLogin']=1;
    //redirect to homepage with successfull message
    header("Location:$base_url/index.php?validationError=$validationError");
}
else
{
    //redirect to login_form with msg
    header("Location:$base_url/login_form.php?validationError=$validationError");
}
```

Now i want to get the username value in a dropdown box field.

below is the code

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM `user`";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $selected = ($val == $row1['username'] ? 'selected="selected"' : '');
    echo '<option value ="' . $row1['username'] . '" '. $selected .'>' . $row1['username'] . '</option>';

}
?>
```

But i am not getting any value in the field.

Comment: Are the rest of the usernames listed in the dropdown menu, and is $val set?

Comment: Please tell me you are using some kind of sanitisation on that data from the form? mysql_* functions have been deprecated in recent versions of PHP. You should really look into using something more secure, like PDO[http://uk1.php.net/PDO] before you even attempt to fix your issue here

Comment: where is `$val` set, and if you echo its value, is it correct?

Comment: First of all (I know it's not what you ask about) is: DO NOT STORE PASSWORDS IN PLAINTEXT. At least use md5 to encrypt them... Secondly, the construction `isset($validationError) && $validationError==0` seems strange. Not sure how it will behave but you should declare some default value at the start and change this if to `$validationError === 0`)...

Comment: @Moby04: md5 is about as much use as storing them in plaintext.

Comment: @PeteR: That's why I wrote "at least" I know it should get some salt (preferably user dependent) and use some better hash function.